# Is there a way to prevent pasting after checking the selection?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am looking for a way to prevent the user from pasting depending on their copied selection and pasting selection (e.g. stop the user from pasting a column if they copied an entire row and vice versa).

I've looked into the `beforePaste()` method and other members related to the `copyPaste` plugin, but I can't find any way to stop the paste.

Ideally, I want the user's selected range to remain the same, but without any data being pasted.

Comment: I think this requires a little more information, is there any reason you can't use an onchange event on the input field to validate the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beforePaste` is not a method. It's a callback, or a `hook` in Handsontable nomenclature.

If `beforePaste` hook returns `false` the action will not be executed. Try this:

```
hot.addHook('beforePaste', function () {
  if (whatever) {
    return false;
  }
});
```